# Tomcat Eclipse Plugin Default Parameters?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

We are debugging an issue on an application running on Tomcat, I am trying to figure out what parameters are passed as default when we start tomcat from Eclipse. We are more interested to find values for following:

1. user.language
2. user.region

While running from command line we use startup.sh or startup.bat on linus or windows respectively. But when we start tomcat from plugin, does it call bat file or execute a jar ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is neither, it uses a Run Configuration, which doesn't package into a war, or launch through a bar file.

If you look in Run->Run Configurations, then you can see all of the parameters (including classpath, etc) that are used when you launch Tomcat. Anything you don't specify there may be inherited from your Eclipse (such as user.language etc).